# Django with IronPython and VS2010?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2010, ironpython, pycharm

I have just checked JetBrains products page and noticed they have a new product - PyCharm that supports Django out of the box for Python development.

Is there a plug-in or a native support for Django in Visual Studio 2010 with IronPython?

Comment: PyCharm is pretty terrific, like all JetBrains products.

Comment: +1 Never knew about Pycharm.  I've been using Eclipse with Pydev.  Its like a glorified text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MS is no longer officially working on IronPython, you may consider PyCharm.  I come from Asp.net and recently moved to Django and happen to use PyCharm and overall am happy with it.  Especially because I can work on the same code from my PC or Mac with it.  There were some gotches that got me for a bit with it, like it didn't come with Django it's a separate install (it's documented) just surprised me coming from VS.

Comment: IronPython isn't going anywhere, and it's still great to develop in. Being able to interface with the entire world of .net assemblies out there (and getting to write python while doing it) personally has me hooked.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft did open-source release of Python tools for Visual Studio.NET

The announcement can be found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2011/08/29/python-tools-for-visual-studio.aspx

The Python tools itself could be found at http://pytools.codeplex.com/

It supports CPython, IronPython, Jython, and PyPy. So Django development has to be a breeze now in VS.NET. I am still checking out though.

Comment: There is a support for django in current version of Python Tools for VS (1.5RC; probably introduces in some erlier version)